# rails, how to pass users id while on 'show' action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, parameters, hidden-field

im on a users profile, ie the path is...

```
http://localhost:3000/users/2
```

i have a text field so the current user (me) can send a private message to user 2 while on his profile page.

how can i retrieve the users id and pass it in a hidden field?

```
<div><%= f.hidden_field :????, :value => ???? %></div>
```

thanks. the hidden tag field is in a form. here is the form if its helpful

```
<%= form_for(current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Send a private message" %>
  </div>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :private, :value => "true" %></div>

  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try having nested routes, e.g.

```
resources :users do
  resources :microposts
end
```

and then use

```
<%= form_for([current_user, @micropost])  do |f| %>
```

I try to avoid a hidden fields generally in rails, it usually means I've missed a convention.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you'll have:

`@user = User.find(params[:id])`

So:

`<div><%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => @user.id %></div>`

Comment: Looks to me like the user object is already available in `current_user`, so you can avoid the extra call in the controller.

Comment: They're in the show action so that call is probably already there. They want the user whose profile they're on, not the current_user.

Comment: hmmm is there any other way to do this? because in order to pass in the :user_id, i have to make :user_id attri_accessible and i heard its not very safe to do so. is there another way to somehow get the users id im currently looking at when it enters the create action in my Micropost controller?